# C# Generic class: infer non-nullable type from nullable type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, nullable-reference-types, non-nullable, c#-9.0

I use C# 8 nullable reference types.

I have a generic class that might accept nullable reference type as a type parameter.

**Is there a way to declare non-nullable type based on generic type parameter that might be nullable reference type (or even Nullable struct)?**

```
abstract class Selector<T>
{
    T SelectedItem;

    // how to make item parameter not nullable?
    abstract string Format(T! item);

    // how to make item parameter not nullable?
    Func<T!, string> FormatFunction;
}
```

Comment: You should look into using the attributes instead of the `!` and `?` symbols to denote nullability. Since nullable value types and reference types are implemented completely different, there is no easy common way to deal with both.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DisallowNullAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.disallownullattribute?view=netcore-3.1):

```cs
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

abstract class Selector<T>
{
    T SelectedItem;

    public abstract string Format([DisallowNull] T item);
}

var selector = default(Selector<string?>)!;
selector.Format(null); //warning CS8625: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.
```

Comment: Oh, I just realized that I need it also for delegate like Action<T> or a custom delegate. Is it possible at least for reference types?

Comment: This seems to be a good choice but this attributes are not available for .Net Framework. Are there any hints to use them in .Net Framework?

Comment: You can define them yourself - just make sure they are internal.